# How to allow API call only from the same origin/ domain?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cross-browser, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

So I have run into a problem. I am building a javacript file, which appends an iframe into clients page (within a div). Lets say, this iframe is loaded from http://example.com/iframe. iframe's backend module (to handle form submission; written in spring) has some endpoints like http://example.com/url1, http://example.com/url2

Now, I want only the iframe to be able to communicate with backend APIs. Currently, I can hit the iframe backend APIs from localmachine too.

I have come across the referer HTTP field, and initially was planning to set a referer filter on the APIs, but later found out that this can easily be spoofed. Will I get any benifit sertting CORS header on the APIs and setting the origin as http://example.com? Will it work, and if yes, is this a safe and dependable solution? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: X-Frame-Options might help with setting SAMEORIGIN

Comment: Actually iframe is not the issue here. I just want the backend apis to be accessible only by the iframe html (same domain - example.com)

Comment: @TahniatAshraf There is nothing to do. The default CORS configuration should handle it.